# Git worktree adds out of date branch

Tags: git, github

I am working on an my repository and created new branch `practice`. I made two commits from VScode and created pull request on github. On my raspberry pi, where I had clone of master branch,in project folder, I created worktree.

```
$ git worktree add ../practice practice
```

When I checked new folder, it has only one commit instead of twos.So, HEAD is on         previous commit, I think. And when I try  `git pull`

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> practice
```

I can set tracking information or use `git pull <remote> <branch>`. But why `git worktree`
used previous commit? So every time I create new worktree, I didn't need to update it.

Comment: In my experience `worktree add` does not automatically create a tracking branch, unlike `switch` and `checkout`.

Comment: Run `git fetch` first if needed, then use `git worktree add --track -b practice ../practice origin/practice` to be completely explicit (note that this assumes you do not already have a branch named `practice`). This *should* be the default behavior for most cases, though.

Comment: If you'll show the exact sequence of commands you used, we can probably show you where things went wrong in your case.

Comment: You don't create a branch from a hosting site. You create a branch by using `git checkout -b`, `git branch`, etc. If you use a hosting site to create a branch name *on* the hosting site, that does a `git checkout -b` or `git branch` or similar on that site. When you clone a repository, you get all of its commits and *none of its branches*. Your clone ends by creating *one* branch (of a name of your choice), and you then work in this clone.

Comment: @torek I created branch from github, then checkout it from vscode on my pc windows, then made two commits (unit this all was just button pushes). Pretty routine staff nothing went wrong. I checked github on browser and branch was uptodate. Then on raspberry pi, I navigated to my  repos directory and use worktree command, as shown above. Also, I remembered, after first commit, on github create pull request appeared and I created it. On second commit it doesn't required pull request. It seemed strange, why I need to renew pull request every time I make new commit and how should I renew pull req.

Comment: When you use `git checkout` on your local clone, you're telling GIt to *create a new branch* (based on the `origin/` remote-tracking name). If you're sharing the repository and working tree across some sort of networked file system between the laptop and the rpi, don't do that: keep a separate clone on the rpi.

Answer (score 0):

> But why git worktree used previous commit?

Probably because the local repository (on Raspberry Pi) either did not have a practice branch, or had one without the new commits you created.

Before using the `worktree` command, you would need to `git fetch`, and `git branch --track practice origin/practice`, in order to make sure the local branch practice is there.